# KeyError: 'document' occures when I try to use execute_script command in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have simple code. Firstly I get an input from user. In target page, there is an editable div. I focus on it and insert the message that I got from user. When I focusing and inserting element I use Javascript so for using Javascript with Python Selenium I use `execute_script` command.

Code:

```py
message = input()
message = message.replace("'","\\'")
message = message.replace('"','\\"')
browser.execute_script("setTimeout(function() {document.querySelector('._3ee1T ._3uMse ._2FVVk ._3FRCZ').focus();}, 0); document.querySelector('._3ee1T ._3uMse ._2FVVk ._3FRCZ').textContent = '{}'".format(message))
```

Error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 171, in <module> browser.execute_script("setTimeout(function() {document.querySelector('._3ee1T  ._3uMse ._2FVVk ._3FRCZ').focus();}, 0); document.querySelector('._3ee1T ._3uMse ._2FVVk ._3FRCZ').textContent = '{}'".format(message)) KeyError: 'document'`

Comment: I think your format call is inserting into "{document.querySelector('._3ee1T ._3uMse ._2FVVk ._3FRCZ').focus();}"  (and it's getting very confused by that...) Not sure why you don't just use Selenium's send_keys here...

Comment: the "editable div" will at some point contain an input field.  You'll want to target that for entering text.

Comment: @pcalkins yes it worked, I thought I tried it before but I did not surprisingly. But I still wonder why `execute_script` command doesn't working.